# Mysqldump - problem with a path

Tags: syntax, mysql

I want to save my currently database on localhost to file. I am trying to do this with following command in my terminal (Mac - Snow leopard):

```
mysqldump my_database > dump.sql
```

And I am still getting an error **ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near...**

I am log in to mysql and normally working with database, but I can't do back up my database.
I guess the problem could be in a path to my database... but I don't know, how to fix it...

Can someone an experience with this problem?

Thank you,
M.

Comment: From the looks of it, you're typing it into the mysql's console instead of just shell.

Comment: Damn, so stupid fault... the solution is **mysqldump -u root -p --databases your_database > dumpfile.sql*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get out from `mysql` prompt.

```
mysql>exit
```

and run the command

```
mysqldump -u root -p my_database > dump.sql
```